# pegar href com base em uma class

Tags: node.js

preciso da ajuda de voces no seguite problema para automatizar uma tarefa, tenho uma class="atender" é o que diferencial dos outros links, com base nesta class preciso pegar o link que muda a cada cliente, segue parte do codigo

```
<tr data-id="b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d"  data-name="ANA PAULA" class="answer">
<td data-type="System.String" data-attribute="pmc_name_client" data-value="ANA PAULA" tabindex="0" data-th="Name Client" aria-label="Name Client ANA PAULA">
<a href="/oportunidades/detalhes-oportunidade/?id=b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d" class="details-link has-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show detail">ANA PAULA</a></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
´<tr data-id="b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d"  
data-name="ANA PAULA" class="answer">
<td data-type="System.String" data- 
attribute="pmc_name_client" data-value="ANA PAULA" 
tabindex="0" data-th="Name Client" aria-label="Name 
Client ANA PAULA">
<a href="/oportunidades/detalhes-oportunidade/? 
id=b5d1a5c7-ad27-4a80-b9ea-80b20ba63f4d" 
class="details-link has-tooltip" data- 
toggle="tooltip" title="Show detail">ANA PAULA</a> 
</td></tr>´
```